# How to know which method is called in Laravel controller

Tags: laravel, magic-methods

When a request comes to Laravel controller through application router, how can we determine which method is called inside that controller? I mean inside **constructor** or **magic methods** of the controller. Is it possible to know?

Consider the method that is called exists. So `__call` would not be the solution.

I have this Route:

```
Route::get('exam', [ExamController::class,'index']);
```

And I want to get `index` inside `ExamController` class. maybe in side `__construct` or ...

```
public function __construct()
{
    // here I want to access the name of called method
}
```

`__call` magic method just give the method name if the method is'nt exist:

```
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    // I have access to $method name here (index)
}
```

Comment: What 'problem' are you trying to solve here?

Comment: Trying get the called method name and set an middleware on them if there are those specific methods that I want to protect them.I need to pass method name to the middleware. Here is where the question comes from

Comment: I don't understand why you would define a route and not define the associated function. Regardless I have updated my answer to provide a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `__FUNCTION__` or `__METHOD__` PHP constants to obtain information about the function or class and function:

```
class SomeClass
{
    public function aFunction()
    {
        echo __FUNCTION__;
    }

    public function anotherFunction()
    {
        echo __METHOD__;
    }
}

$obj = new SomeClass();
$obj->aFunction(); // aFunction
$obj->anotherFunction(); // SomeClass::anotherFunction
```

**Update**

Let's assume whilst you might not have a function defined for a specific route, you know the name of a route you want to apply a specific middleware to. You can apply middelware to specific functions from the controller constructor:

```
public function  __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth', ['only' => ['index', 'create']]);
}
```

Alternatively just specify the middleware required for the route on the route definition.

Comment: These constants say where are you now. I want to know which method of class is called inside class constructor.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide an example in your question of what you want to achieve. That might clear things up.